# How to Truncate a STRING in LOGICAPPS?

Tags: logic

We have some addresses that are greater than 30 characters and I have to truncate those to a maximum of 30 characters. What I am trying to do is:

```json
"value": "@{substring(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['address1'],0,29)}"
```

The error I am getting is:

> Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Set_variable' inputs at line '1' and column '2956': 'The template language function 'substring' parameters are out of range: 'start index' and 'length' must be non-negative integers and their sum must be no larger than the length of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
@{substring(string(body('Parse_JSON_2')?['address1'],0,29))}
```